# Property 'Item' is 'ReadOnly'

Tags: vb.net

I wonder if someone could assist me. I'm very new to programming and development (and so I apologise if this is a silly question) but I am pretty stuck on a project I am currently working on.

I am coding a WinForms application which is due to run once a day to retrieve information from a database. From this, it is to automatically email individuals in the building if particular criteria is met. The message body is to contain various details that were brought into the datagrid.

At the moment, my application is crashing when it tries to transfer the details over to the sub responsible for generating the email (as some of the variables are returning as 'Null' and so cannot be converted to a string). I am trying to implement an If statement to assign a string to the variable if it returns as Null, as below:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RunTimer.Tick

    years = My.Settings.Years.Split(",")

    If TimeOfDay = "09:00:00" Then
        Using cn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
            cn.ConnectionString = constr
            cn.Open()

            SQLstr = "long SQL string that works as have run it in WinSQL"

            Using command As New SqlClient.SqlCommand(SQLstr, cn)
                command.CommandTimeout = 0
                command.CommandText = SQLstr
                Using drd As SqlClient.SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader
                    While drd.Read

                        If Not drd("Joined Date") Is DBNull.Value Then
                            Dim memberyears As Integer = DateDiff(DateInterval.Year, drd("Joined Date"), Now)
                            Dim element As Integer

                            For element = 0 To years.GetUpperBound(0)
                                If years(element) = memberyears Then
                                    Label1.Text = "Sending email"
                                End If
                                If Not drd("City") Is DBNull.Value Then
                                    drd("City") = "Bleh"
                                End If
                                SendEmail(years(element), drd("Shop Name"), drd("Contact Name"), drd("Shop ID"), drd("Business Name"), drd("Address 1"), drd("Address 2"), drd("Address 3"), drd("District"), drd("City"), drd("County"), drd("Shop Postal Code"), drd("ASM"))
                            Next
                        End If
                    End While
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using


    Else
        Label1.Text = "Skipped"
        Exit Sub
    End If

End Sub
```

The `If` statement I am working on is this:

```
If Not drd("City") Is DBNull.Value Then
    drd("City") = "Bleh"
End If
```

However it just returns as Property 'Item' is ReadOnly. Any help would be greatly appreciated on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot change a field of a record of a `SqlDataReader`. The `DataReader` is used to read data only. If you want to modify it you ca use a `DataTable`/`DataRow` and use it's [`IsNull`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.isnull.aspx) method to check if the value of a field is null:

```
Using cn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(constr)
    Using da = New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter("long SQL string that works as have run it in WinSQL", cn)
        da.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 0
        Dim table = New DataTable()
        da.Fill(table)
        For Each row As DataRow In table.Rows
            If Not row.IsNull("Joined Date") Then
                Dim joined = row.Field(Of Date)("Joined Date")
                Dim memberyears As Long = DateDiff(DateInterval.Year, joined, Date.Now)
                For i As Int32 = 0 To years.Length - 1
                    If memberyears.ToString = years(i) Then
                        Label1.Text = "Sending email"
                        If Not row.IsNull("City") Then
                            row("City") = "Bleh"
                        End If
                        SendEmail(years(i), row("Shop Name"), row("Contact Name"), row("Shop ID"), row("Business Name"), row("Address 1"), row("Address 2"), row("Address 3"), row("District"), row("City"), row("County"), row("Shop Postal Code"), row("ASM"))
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        Next
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: Thanks for your response :) can I presume that if there are other variables such as county, district etc then I can just use a similar if statement as has been done for city?

Comment: @ChrisWright: Yes. Note that you also should use `row.Field(Of String)("City")` instead since the [`Field`-method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.field(v=vs.90).aspx) is strongly typed(doesn't return `Object`) and also support `Nullable`-types. So you could even write: `row.Field(Of Date)("Joined Date").HasValue` to check if the date is null.

Comment: I tried adding in all of the other variables that could potentially be Null and although this is now working perfectly for some of them, on others the Null Value is still being transferred?

Comment: Certainly:

If Not row.IsNull("Address 2") Then
                                        row("Address 2") = "Bleh"
                                    End If

                                    If Not row.IsNull("Address 3") Then
                                        row("Address 3") = "Invalid"
                                    End If

Address 2 transmits 'Bleh', but Address 3 still returns as Null

Comment: @ChrisWright: That's not possible if `row("Address 3")` is really `DBNull.Value`. Are you sure that it's null(use the debugger) or is it possible that it's just empty(one or multiple white-space characters). Then you need this code: `If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(row.Field(Of String)("Address 3")) Then
                            row.SetField("Address 3", "Invalid")
                        End If`

Comment: Many thanks, that seemed to do the trick :) one out of three issues now resolved with my application. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. It is a `read only` property,

Solution for this will be having a `variable` to hold the value from `database`.But, note this, before assigning to that `variable`, we must check whether it is `DbNull` or not.

```
       Dim xCity as string = string.empty

       ....................
       ....................
       ....................

       xCity = if(IsDbNull(drd("City")),"some text","some other text")
```

Then use that variable `xCity` for your future usage.

**Edit:**

If suppose you want to avoid that additional variable, then you can directly check that value and pass a valid string like this,

```
SendEmail(**,**, if(IsDbNull(drd("City")),"some text","some other text"), **, **, **)
```

Comment: This seems to make a lot of logical sense, however when I tried debugging it complained that it could not convert to a string fro a Null value

Comment: Even with using that string it returns 'Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'String' is not valid.'

Comment: @ChrisWright did you try using .ToString(), like drd("City").toString().

Comment: In the line for SendEmail I simply copied the code you kindly provided to overwrite the old code for drd("City")

Comment: @ChrisWright are you facing any issues now.? if so just tell me exactly, in which line the error is raising. :)

Comment: The error with transmitting Null values has now been rectified, thank you for your time and assistance :)